# Using ggplot2 to print text with '\n' in them

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create an image in ggplot with geom_text, but the text overlaps itself. I thought I could be clever and add an `\n` in my csv file where I get the data from, but it did not work, in fact it made it worse. How do I plot multi-line text in geom_text? I do not want to use ggrepl as that defeats the purpose of my specific plotting for each text. Also, how would I remove the extra `\` in my labels? They are read from a csv file.

```
xx <- seq(1,5,1)
yy <- seq(1,5,1)
labelss <-c ('My\\n1 Label','My\\n2 Label','My\\n3 Label','My\\n4 Label','My\\n5 Label')
df<-data.frame(xx,yy,labelss)
ggplot()+
  geom_tile(aes(xx, yy), df) +
  geom_text(aes(xx, yy, label = labelss), color ='white', df, size=3)
```

Comment: In R, the `\n` special character contains only a single backslash. In this case, use `'My\n1 Label'` (etc). (Note that your second one is missing the `n`, showing just `My\\2`.

Comment: that has been fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to double escape the backslashes in a `gsub` call. As @r2evans says, the second label had a missing n, so I've added it to this reprex:

```r
library(ggplot2)

xx <- seq(1,5,1)
yy <- seq(1,5,1)
labelss <-c ('My\\n1 Label','My\\n2 Label','My\\n3 Label','My\\n4 Label','My\\n5 Label')
df<-data.frame(xx,yy,labelss)
ggplot()+
  geom_tile(aes(xx, yy), df) +
  geom_text(aes(xx, yy, label = gsub("\\\\n", "\n", labelss)), color ='white', df, size=3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Why the need to create it with `\\n` and then `gsub` to fix it? I didn't get the idea from the OP that the data came this way, just that the `\\n` was being added.

Comment: @r2evans mu understanding was that this was how the text came from the csv.

Comment: ok, I misunderstood *"I thought I could be clever and add an `\n` in my csv file"*, thinking you added it after reading it in. Thanks.

Comment: So I actually had to create this in python and the python way is df.labelss.apply(lambda x: re.sub("\\\\n", "\n", x)).